# Weird glyphicon appearing and not rendering with bootstrap-select

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I've implemented a select-drop down list with bootstrap-select, but for some reason some strange glyphicons are appearing unintentionally and not rendering, and as a result are appearing as squares after each station name within this app.

Here is the app: http://radiant-taiga-9193.herokuapp.com/

Here is the relevant code that renders after each station name with the glyphicon:

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i>
```

Here is my attempt at a fix which has failed:

```
.glphicon, .glyphicon-ok, .icon-ok, .checkmark {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that Bootstrap 3 uses `span`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
.check-mark { display: none !important }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not loading the font files correctly. Check the console, as you get 404 errors for the fonts.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://radiant-taiga-9193.herokuapp.com/assets/twitter/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://radiant-taiga-9193.herokuapp.com/assets/twitter/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://radiant-taiga-9193.herokuapp.com/assets/twitter/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular
```

Comment: Strange. I have twitter-bootstrap-rails in my gemfile. Is there any reason why this may not be loading? What is the best way to fix this

Comment: I've never used Heroku, so I can't help you with that.